# How to get out of this my net banking web page is autoloading the username and password

Tags: windows-7, internet

I tried to login to ingvysya internet banking in IE9 winnows 7 64 bit from my office i got an error message that java is not supporting once I close the window and reopen the net banking secured web page it takes my credentials automatically and shows the error, not able to login as different user. How to go out of this automatic logging in please its very urgent.  I unchecked the autoloading and deleted all the histories and tried the cookies and security setiings but didn't work. The automatic logging in to net banking should go off and normal blank logging in page should open for net banking please help me it's really emergency.

Answer (score 1):

Clear all caches!!! In Firefox and IE you should be able to press the CTRL+ALT+Shift buttons to bring up a window where you can do it. This might not work depending on your browsers security settings and if that happens you will probably need to get to it through your browsers options settings. Then use something like CCleaner ( http://www.piriform.com/ ) to get any other tidbits that may not be getting cleared.

Once all that is done, check your browsers add-ons and plugins to make sure everything is up to date. Quite frankly, it sounds like you may not have updated Flash and it desperately needs to do so. There should even be an icon for Flash settings in your Control Panel too. But if it's not there then you almost certainly have an ancient Flash version that probably needs to be removed before even a newer version can be installed.

Do the same with Java if you have that too. Java is now into version 7.x where anything less probably needs to be removed as well.

Run an AV/AM (anti virus / anti malware) scan to be sure you don't have a nasty old piece of worm poo or something. OK, not literally, but you get the idea. (I won't harp on that since it's a little too obvious.)

You might then want to follow up by checking your browser settings and make sure there isn't some kind of tool bar causing problems or that your DNS settings were mucked with or something like that. And if you're connected to the Internet through your company you may want to follow up with your IT department to make sure they aren't doing something.

But here's the thing: If you do any banking or anything sensitive like that at a open public WiFi hot spot (like Starbucks, McDonalds or somewhere) - DON'T!!! You must - and I repeat MUST - use a secure PPTP connection to a trusted connection before even thinking about something like that. Basically, that's like setting up an encrypted connection through the open Internet connection to somewhere like your home or business where you *then* "securely" connect via the Internet again to whatever site you want to do business with. So if you're not on your own "secure" connection then you're just asking to have you identity stolen and/or your bank accounts drained. (Want to know more, try Googling "Man in the middle attacks" - and that's only one reason.)

Please be careful! Maybe it's time you go to your bank or at least call them. Here's another reason why you may want to reconsider just who you bank with too: http://betanews.com/2012/07/25/malware-infects-three-quarters-of-the-worlds-top-banks/ Then again, maybe that's just one more reason to look for a good old fashioned credit union instead. But I digress...